# Find an XML child node 

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have this type of XML -

```
<leadareas>
<pho>   
    <phoName>NWPHO</phoName>
    <csName>nw_btn</csName>

    <phoTit1>Drugs</phoTit1>
    <phoTit2>Sexual Health</phoTit2>
    <phoTit3>Violence</phoTit3>
    <phoTit4>Alcohol</phoTit4>

</pho>
<pho>   
    <csName>ne_btn</csName>
    <phoName>NEPHO</phoName>
    <phoTit1>ne1</phoTit1>
    <phoTit2>Something else</phoTit2>
    <phoTit3>another</phoTit3>


</pho>
</leadareas>
```

I would like to write a function where for example phoTit1 is returned where csname = ne_btn, but dont know if this is possible?  Any ideas please?

Answer (score 4):

I've sussed it out if anyone's interested!

```
var nodeRec:XML =navData.pho.(csname =="ne_btn")

return nodeRec.phoTit1
```